# Typesafe factory function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have two functions:

```
const createPerson = (age: number, name: string) => {};

const createCar = (model: string) => {}
```

I wish to create a generic factory function that accepts an argument and based on that argument returns one of the two functions. Something like:

```
enum Argument {
    Person = 'person',
    Car = 'car'
}

type Pairs = {
    [Argument.Person]: typeof createPerson;
    [Argument.Car]: typeof createCar;
}

const factory = <K extends keyof Pairs>(type: K): Pairs[K] => {
    if (type === Argument.Person) return createPerson;
    if (type === Argument.Car) return createCar
};
```

It's all fine and dandy but the `Pairs[K]` seems to be causing problems as I get an error:

```
Type '(age: number, name: string) => void' is not assignable to type 'Pairs[K]'.
  Type '(age: number, name: string) => void' is not assignable to type '((age: number, name: string) => void) & ((model: string) => void)'.
    Type '(age: number, name: string) => void' is not assignable to type '(model: string) => void'.
```

How can I make it not merge the two types (as it's evident from the error message, `&`)?

Comment: Use overloads instead of generics for this kind of thing. Or move the generics into an external signature so it doesn't get in your way.

Comment: Is this [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Factories are supposed to hide construction logic and give you *something* without the caller needing to know what specific thing it is. Your requirement goes directly against the grain - the caller needs to know what specific object would be created, *supply* that information to the factory, and also *get back* the information. To have the factory work this way, you need to basically destroy the value it gives you by exposing almost everything about it.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can avoid the problems with the generic return type by indexing an object of pairs:

```
const pairs = {
    [Argument.Person]: createPerson,
    [Argument.Car]: createCar,
}

type Pairs = typeof pairs

const factory = <K extends keyof Pairs>(type: K): Pairs[K] => pairs[type]
```

[TypeScript playground](https://tsplay.dev/w61dGW)